# Can my app detect that it was opened by Siri?

Tags: swift, siri

Can my Swift app detect that it was opened by `Siri`? I'd like to open to a specific `viewController` if (and only if) my app was opened by Siri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is unfortunately not possible yet. You can read at the [SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH11-SW1) what´s possible to do and not. This is the first version of SiriKit, it will probably come later.

Comment: It became possible in watchOS3.2, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It became possible in watchOS3.2. in your ExtensionDelegate, implement the function [handle(userActivity)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkextensiondelegate/2798966-handleactivity). If your app is opened from Siri,  `userActivity.activityType` will be the name of the INIntentResponse that was provided by your IntentHandler, so you just have to check if `userActivity.activityType` equals any of the INIntentResponse names that your Intents Extension can handle.

Comment: Is there a way to detect it in an extension? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56996618/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-user-was-already-in-your-app-before-launching-siri

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it with the delegate method of `SceneDelegate`

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        if userActivity.interaction?.intent is YourIntentName {
            // App launched via that particular shortcut.
        }
    }
}
```

Note: here `YourIntentName` is the name of Intent in your `.intentdefinition` file

Answer (score -1):

Putting this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions worked for me on initial launch.

**Objc:**

`BOOL startedFromSiri = ([[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey] isEqualToString:@"com.apple.assistant.assistantd"]) ? YES : NO;`

**Swift:**

`let startedFromSiri: Bool = (launchOptions[.sourceApplication] == "com.apple.assistant.assistantd") ? true : false`

Comment: launchOptions is always arriving nil for me