# Is there a way to detect if user was already in your app before launching Siri?

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit

Is this possible to know inside my Siri intent handler if the user was in my app before launching Siri?

Answer (score 0):

You can use App Groups to share data between your app's main target and your Siri intent handler. You could simply store a `Bool` in `UserDefaults` indicating whether your app was already launched or not, then access the same value using App Groups from your Siri intent handler.

For more information on App Groups, see the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html).